# Which tables "Partner functions" information stored in SAP ERP database?

Tags: sap-erp

One of the customers that I have in SAP has several ship-to addresses. I need to pull those addresses from SAP database directly and don't know what tables I should refer to, and, if there is more than one table how the data is related?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the table, it is KNVP.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's a bad idea to access the database directly. Why that is so has been discussed numerous times here.

To find out the tables involved, a good starting point would be to enable the SQL trace (ST05), access some function that shows the data, then disable the trace again and sift through the results of the trace.

Comment: Is there a BAPI call to get the list of all ship-to ("WE") addresses?